# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Adafruit'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython

I was working with a code I found online, it had:

```
from Adafruit import ADS1x15

...
t = time.perf_counter() - t0
adc.stopContinuousConversion()
print('Time elapsed: %.9f s.' % t)
print()
```

But it kept showing me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Aryannn\Downloads\project\child.py", line 15, in <module>
from Adafruit import ADS1x15
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Adafruit'
```

I am a bit new to Raspberry Pi so I bought it here to ask. It would be really great if you help me out here

Comment: Where does `Adafruit` come from? Is it a library you need to install? If so, have you installed it?

Comment: I have the same question cause I googled it and it didn't show me a library like that, But it was in the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looking for the python library Adafruit's ADS1x15.

From https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_ADS1x15, it looks to be deprecated.  In its place, it's supposedly https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_ADS1x15.

That said, if you do need to use the current version, I believe it is:

```
# Import the ADS1x15 module.
import Adafruit_ADS1x15


# Create an ADS1115 ADC (16-bit) instance.
adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()
```